# How can i use custom hooks inside my function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to use my hook inside a function but it doesn't work, so now i tried to send a callback function to reset the hook params but it is still not working.

How can i make this custom hook work in my case?

```
const del = useFetch(null);
  const handleDelete = id => {
    del.setParams({
       hookUrl: "https://localhost:44354/api/car/" + id, 
       hookOptions: {}
    });

    console.log(del.response);
  };
```

The hook works fine for GETS cause i dont have any other behavior i want to do, but for the delete i need to pop a modal for example, i know i can use the fetch directly but just curious.

```
import React from "react";

const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  debugger;
  const [params, setParams] = React.useState({
    hookUrl: url,
    hookOptions: options
  });
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(params.hookUrl, params.hookOptions);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { setParams, response, error };
};
export default useFetch;
```

Comment: `useFetch()` must be supplied with two arguments, you just gave it `null`?  setParams also takes an object, yet you're supplying two values of string and empty object. Check that and im sure you're gonna be fine

Comment: just like the response i'm supposed to send json which i corrected but still it's not working guess i just cant useFetch inside a function no matter what i try :( @Claeusdev

Comment: I think you might wanna pass another null value for `options` and see

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use a hook inside a function.
2. You are using the setParams (setState in a wrong way):

```
const handleDelete = id => {
    del.setParams({
       hookUrl: "https://localhost:44354/api/car/" + id, 
       hookOptions: {}
    });
    console.log(del.response);
  };
```